# Should I roll back this answer edit? Is there a better way to handle this?

Tags: discussion, edits, answers, rollbacks

This answer was originally posted in 2009. This March, 5 years and 3 months later, someone else decided to remove nearly any trace of the original answer (the only thing preserved was the documentation URL that the answer cited) and replaced it with their own answer.

It seems really bizarre to me - the comments that were made when the original answer was there no longer make any sense with this new answer, and any upvotes that this now gets goes to the person who wrote the original answer, not the answer that any voter probably intends to give it to.

Is there some way to force this to be posted as a new answer, or is all we can do request that the editor roll back their edits and post a new answer?

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1884142/revisions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> replaced it with their own answer

It's not *really* their own answer.

Rinzler has only taken the code from the original link destination and put it into the answer, and still left a link to the original source.

This seems like a good edit to me.

Rinzler also added a bit more information and helpful intro to the code. And updated the code a bit.

The code *comments* seem ok and improved, although I do not know Python at all so don't know if the code changes are right. I can see some code changes only appear to be esthetic changes.

However, some are changes the code itself, e.g.:

```
// FROM (original link destination)
raise TclError, "cannot use pack with this widget"

// TO (Rinzler's edit)
raise TclError("cannot use pack with this widget")
```

You can see the entire differences clearly here:

Original source on the left, Rinzler's edit on the right:
https://www.diffchecker.com/knzmcvj6

---

> any upvotes that this now gets goes to the person who wrote the
>   original answer, not the answer that any voter probably intends to
>   give it to

Any upvotes goes to the user who made the original answer, which is in their favour as it's been improved in my opinion. They can roll back if they wish.

As for others voting and giving rep to the original answerer, does it matter?  They are voting on the answer content, and this includes any edits by other users.
This is how community driven sites work, we can edit each other's content to improve it, and users can edit again or roll back if it was a bad change (etc).

---

> Is there some way to force this to be posted as a new answer

No.
You can undo Rinzler's actions, but only they can post their own answer.

> or is all we can do request that the editor roll back their edits and
>   post a new answer?

You can request both to Rinzler, or edit/undo to answerer, or suggest an edit yourself removing the changes. But given it's a good edit I'm not sure why you'd want to.

Comment: Wow. I was familiar with the `AutoScrollbar` class defined at that link, but I didn't realize that the example following it answered the exact question. I had thought that the example usage was Rinzler's own original code. You're right. All the edits did was move content from behind a link and embed it directly in the answer. No need for a roll back.

Comment: As long as the few edits to the actual code are ok. I know as much about Python as I have tentacles (and I'm no invertebrate..)

Comment: So you're Dr. Octopus, then? Can't think of any other vertebrates with tentacles...